# Upload secure files to GitLab using requests python module

Tags: python, python-requests, gitlab-api

I'm trying to upload a secure file to my repository in GitLab.

While I am able to upload a secure file with curl, I encounter an error when using requests in Python.

my python code:

```
    r = requests.post("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/10186699/secure_files",
                  headers={"PRIVATE-TOKEN": "glpat-TH7FM3nThKmHgOp"},
                  files={"file": open("/Users/me/Desktop/dev/web-server/utils/a.txt", "r"),
                         "name": "a.txt"}) 
    print(r.status_code,r.json())
```

Response:

```
400 {'error': 'name is invalid'}
```

The equivalent curl command I use that actually works:

```
curl --request POST --header  "PRIVATE-TOKEN: glpat-TH7FM3nThKmHgOp" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/10186699/secure_files --form "name=a.txt" --form "file=@/Users/me/Desktop/dev/web-server/utils/a.txt"
```

Comment: I think you are passing `name` double time. One in `open` method called `a.txt` and another time in `"name" : "a.txt"`. Take a look at `requests.post` documents for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent call will be

```
import requests

resp = requests.post(
    "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/10186699/secure_files",
    headers={"PRIVATE-TOKEN": "glpat-TH7FM3nThKmHgOp"},
    files={"file": open("/Users/me/Desktop/dev/web-server/utils/a.txt", "rb")},
    data={"name": "a.txt"}
) 

print(resp.status_code,resp.json())
```

This is because the `file=` parameter is intended only for uploading files. On the other hand, `name` is your form data (you need to pass in the `data=` parameter).

It's also recommended to open files in binary mode. ([docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file))